# bash nested read with confirmation

Tags: bash

I'm trying to loop over each line of output from a `grep` and do something conditionally based on an interactive prompt.

I've looked at these:
[Iterating over each line of ls -l output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859908/iterating-over-each-line-of-ls-l-output)

[bash: nested interactive read within a loop that's also using read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704353/bash-nested-interactive-read-within-a-loop-thats-also-using-read)

[Does bash support doing a read nested within a read loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308110/does-bash-support-doing-a-read-nested-within-a-read-loop)

But I'm still having trouble achieving what I want. I think the key difference is most of those examples are reading input from a file - I want to use a command. I've tried many variations of the following:

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                        

function test1()                                                                    
{                                                                                   
    local out=$(grep -n -a --color=always "target" file.txt)                                             
    while read -u 3 line; do                                                        
        echo -e "$line"                                                             
        read -r -p "ok? " response                                                  
        echo "you said: $response"                                                  
        if [[ "$response" == 'n' ]]; then                                           
            return                                                                  
        fi                                                                          
    done 3<&0 <<< $out                                                              
}                                                                                   

function test2()                                                                    
{                                                                                   
    grep -n -a --color=always "target" file.txt | while read line; do                                    
        echo -e "$line"                                                             
        read -r -p "ok? " response                                                  
        echo "you said: $response"                                                  
        if [[ "$response" == 'n' ]]; then                                           
            return                                                                  
        fi                                                                          
    done
 }
```

In `test1()` the FD redirection doesn't seem to do what I want. `test2()` seems to just (unsurprisingly) stomp through my second `read`. I assume this is because I need to switch up the FDs in use. I've tried to combine the FD redirection from `test1` into `test2`, but I haven't been able to get that to work with the pipe. I'm using bash version 4.4. What am I missing?

Here is an example run for the two functions above:

```
[~]$ cat file.txt
ksdjfklj target alsdfjaksjf alskdfj asdf asddd

alsdfjlkasjfklasj
asdf
asdfasdfs
target
assjlsadlkfjakls target
target aldkfjalsjdf
[~]$
[~]$ test1
you said: 1:ksdjfklj target alsdfjaksjf alskdfj asdf asddd 6:target 7:assjlsadlkfjakls target 8:target aldkfjalsjdf
you said:
you said:
you said:
you said:
^C
[~]$
[~]$
[~]$ test2
1:ksdjfklj target alsdfjaksjf alskdfj asdf asddd
you said: 6:target
7:assjlsadlkfjakls target
you said: 8:target aldkfjalsjdf
[~]$
```

Comment: It would be great if you show us some input and output.

Answer (score 2):

`done 3<&0 <<< $out` is quite torturous. How about a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) instead?

```
test1() {
    while IFS= read -r -u 3 line; do
        printf '%s' "$line"
        read -r -p "ok? " response
        echo "you said: $response"
        [[ "$response" == [nN]* ]] && return
    done 3< <(
        grep -n -a --color=always "target" file.txt
    )
}
```

`IFS= read -r` is the idiom to grab the line *exactly verbatim*.

In bash you can use `funcname()` or `function funcname` but you don't need both the keyword and the parentheses.

Comment: There is something about a *herestring* into a redirected `stdin` that just doesn't quite sit right...

Answer (score 1):

Reading from `/dev/tty` should work too

```
test2() {
    grep -n -a --color=always "target" file.txt | \
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        printf '%s' "$line"
        read -r -p "ok? " response </dev/tty
        echo "you said: $response"
        [[ "$response" == [nN]* ]] && return
    done
}
```

Comment: This is interesting! The only potential downside I can see is I wouldn't be able to use  `yes` or something to automate the second `read`. I like not having to use FD shenanigans.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
for line in $(grep ...); do
    echo "$line"
    read ...
    # the rest as in your functions
done
```

P.S. sorry for such a bad formatting, I will update it when I get to my computer

Comment: thanks! The trouble with `for` is it iterates over each space delimited token as opposed to each line. I could possibly solve this by setting `IFS` to something other than ' ' but I think that would mess up my second read.