# bash 'ls' can't find the file after checking that file exists

Tags: linux, bash

I have this simple code

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEOUT=60

# call a function that creates a file
LOG_FILE_NAME="/dir/something.txt"
create_a_file(LOG_FILE_NAME)

until [ ! -f ${LOG_FILE_NAME} ] || [ "$TIMEOUT" == "0" ]
do
    echo "Slept 1 second while waiting for file creation"
    sleep 1
    ((TIMEOUT--))
done

for file in $(ls -tr /dir/*.txt); do
    #something
done
```

Most times this works but sometimes I get:
`ls: cannot access /dir/*.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: Also see [How to iterate over files in a directory with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20796200/608639), [Loop through all the files with a specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14505047/608639), [Iterating over each line of ls -l output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2859908/608639) and friends. An [answer in the first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43606356/608639) addresses when the glob does not match.

Comment: `[ ! -f ${LOG_FILE_NAME} ]` use `-e` and not `-f` as there may be a symbolic link or anything that make it not a regular file and fail the `-f` flag test. add quotes around the variable to prevent globbing so write it `[ ! -e "${LOG_FILE_NAME}" ]` instead. `[ "$TIMEOUT" == "0" ]` is testing `TIMEOUT` as a string. If you want an arithmetic test you either write `[ "$TIMEOUT" -eq 0 ]` or benefit from Bash arithmetic expression with `(( 0=--TIMEOUT ))` and you can then remove `((TIMEOUT--))` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Note that `ls` is not part of bash itself, and is not recommended for use in scripts -- as jww's links describe. (See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) as a focused explanation on the topic).

Comment: @Kam : This can NEVER work under bash, because the statement `create_a_file(LOG_FILE_NAME)` is syntactically invalid and the script will abort with _bash: syntax error near unexpected token `LOG_FILE_NAME'_ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ls: cannot access /dir/*.txt: No such file or directory

It means there are no `*.txt` files in `/dir/`. (When the glob doesn't match anything the shell passes the literal asterisk to `ls`, as if you had written `ls '/dir/*.txt'`.)

The problem is the loop condition. It shouldn't have `!`.

```
until [ -f ${LOG_FILE_NAME} ] || [ "$TIMEOUT" == "0" ]
```

(If the timeout hits 0 you'll still see the same error, though.)

It's better to use `[[`, by the way, to avoid quoting issues.

```
until [[ -f $LOG_FILE_NAME || $TIMEOUT == 0 ]]
```

Comment: Ahh. Until you suggested the cutover to `[[`, I was going to recommend switching to `=`, but using explicitly extended-shells-only syntax makes that moot. :)